# Bash script to list all repos of an organization

Tags: bash, api, github

I am trying to create as simple bash script to list all the repos in our organization on github.  Seems like it shouldn't be that hard, so I am sure I am missing something obvious.  Various examples are around, e.g. [1](https://gist.github.com/ralphbean/5733076) but they don't really work.  I have tried

```
curl --user "$USER:$PASS" https://api.github.com/orgs/$ORG/repos
```

where USER and PASS are valid usernames and password and ORG is https://github.com/readium.

But this doesn't work. I just get "message" : "Not Found"

I've tried many variations on this following various threads here and elsewhere but no soap.  Suggestions?

Comment: `ORG` value should be `readium`?

Comment: Are you trying this command directly on the command line? I put the literal values in,my user/pw and readium instead of $ORG and it worked for me. One thing comes to mind is to use single quotes instead in case you have characters bash treats specially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl --user "$USER:$PASS" https://api.github.com/orgs/$ORG/repos |
grep -w 'itemprop="name codeRepository"' |
cut -d/ -f3 | cut -d'"' -f1
```

Ex:

```
curl -u username:password https://github.com/username?tab=repositories |
grep -w 'itemprop="name codeRepository"' |
cut -d/ -f3 | cut -d'"' -f1
```

Comment: @rkwright Does it worked for you. for me it gave me all repos.

Comment: Ah!  I was passing in the URL to the organization (i.e. https://github.com/readium when it only wanted the name of  the organization, i.e. readium.  With that change it works.  The second part of your code doesn't work because there is no 'codeRepository' property.  But what is wanted is 'name' or 'full-name'.  So I am good.  thanks!

Comment: in the link which you have provided has the property of name codeRepository.Actially in github every repo has a property name of this. so we can easily filter . just try to inspect and you will see it

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the way mentioned above, the more secure way would be to generate a token with appropriate permissions.

You can generate a token as well by using `Settings` -> `Personal Access Token` until you get corresponding organisation token. Make sure that you choose the smallest expiry and least permissions.

Once you have access to the token you can use the following command

```bash
curl -H "Authorization: token <your-token-here>" https://api.github.com/orgs/<organization-name-here>/repos
```